# looking for most efficient way to to query multiple email addresses in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for a way to select the email address of joe so that every time i run a select query I get only one email address returning in sequence of the id.  sort of round Robin the results ..

```
      so on first select I get joe@blogs.com 
      and then second I get joe@gmail.com
      and third joe@outlook.com
      and next joe@blogs.com as there are only three entries
```

If you know what I mean.

```
            addresses
            ---------------------
            id|name|email
            ---------------------
            1 |joe |joe@blogs.com
            2 |joe |joe@gmail.com
            3 |joe |joe@outlook.com
```

Comment: Can you also explain what is the goal or what I a requirement triggering this implementation ? And the round robin select is within eceution user or accross all users. Multiple user can run the proc to select data so what is expected behavior for multi user.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
CREATE TABLE #results (id INT, name VARCHAR(50), email VARCHAR(100))
DECLARE @currentID INT;

WHILE(1 = 1)
BEGIN
    SET @currentID =
    (SELECT TOP 1 t.id 
    FROM [YOURTABLE] t
    LEFT JOIN #results r
        ON r.id = t.id
    WHERE t.name = 'joe'
        AND r.id IS NULL)

    IF @currentID IS NULL
        BREAK;

    SELECT * FROM [YOURTABLE] WHERE id = @currentID 

    INSERT INTO #results
    SELECT TOP 1 t.id, t.name, t.email 
    FROM [YOURTABLE] t
    WHERE t.id = @currentID 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to store the next email id in a field that has a foreign key to the user. This will give you the most interoperability between whatever will be using the database.

Be mindful because you will run into issues if emails are deleted.

Comment: what do u mean by stateless?